# Creating an iterative loop in R to read in all Excel files in a folder, performing the same function, and exporting as a new file

Tags: r, excel, iteration, xlsx

My current problem is that I have written the following:

```
list.of.packages <- c("xlsx","dplyr","tidyverse")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
lapply(list.of.packages, require, character.only=T)

setwd("C:/Users/Google Drive/Global MIS/Global profiles/profiles_as_data")

AEC_data <- read.xlsx("G-AEC-DATA.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, as.data.frame = T, check.names = F)

rownames(AEC_data) = make.names(AEC_data$AEC, unique = T)
AEC_data <- tibble::rownames_to_column(AEC_data,"Variable")
AEC_data <- select(AEC_data, -2)

AEC_data_reshaped <- reshape(AEC_data,
                             direction = "long",
                             varying = list(names(AEC_data)[2:17]),
                             v.names = "Value",
                             idvar = "AEC",
                             timevar = "Year",
                             times = 2004:2019)

AEC_data_reshaped <- select(AEC_data_reshaped, -4)
AEC_data_reshaped$Company <- "AEC"

write.xlsx(AEC_data_reshaped, "C:/Users//Google Drive/Global MIS/Global profiles/profiles_as_data_long/G-AEC-DATA-LONG.xlsx", row.names = F, showNA = F)
```

This just reads in G-AEC-DATA.xlsx, manipulates it into long form and does some cleaning. It then outputs it into a new folder with a new name.

My issue is that I have to do this for 30 xlsx files. I basically need to find and replace "AEC" and iterate again for "ABC", say.

I'm guessing I need to set up a list such as:

```
fileNames <- c("AEC.xlsx","ABC.xlsx")
```

for example, then iterate through each file name. All the original files are in exactly the same format, I just need to switch out the ISO3 code and iterate through each file,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do something like this :

```
my_xlsx_files <- dir(path=my_path)
for (file in my_xlsx_files){
   #do what you want here and save
}
```

Comment: I have inserted 

`files <- list.files(path = wd, pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = T)`

which outputs me a list of files and now what I want to do is run the above code to clean it and save it in a different folder. Each file is in the format "G-AEC-DATA.xlsx" with just the "AEC" changing to a different acronym. I basically want to run the above code for each file, replacing AEC with the next acronym on the list.